# flink with scala and maven error in IDE eclipse

Tags: scala, maven, apache-flink

I created this sample program using the doucmentation
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.8/programming_guide.html#introduction

I get the following error running in IDE

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.flink.api.scala.ClosureCleaner$).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while loading the local executor (org.apache.flink.client.LocalExecutor).
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.PlanExecutor.createLocalExecutor(PlanExecutor.java:161)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.LocalEnvironment.startNewSession(LocalEnvironment.java:122)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.LocalEnvironment.execute(LocalEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:855)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.collect(DataSet.java:410)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.print(DataSet.java:1605)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet.print(DataSet.scala:1615)
    at com.sc.edl.flink.ingestion$.main(ingestion.scala:27)
    at com.sc.edl.flink.ingestion.main(ingestion.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.flink.client.LocalExecutor.<init>(org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.PlanExecutor.createLocalExecutor(PlanExecutor.java:158)
```

Can someone please let me know what is wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That documentation page is for version 0.8. Retry with an updated version (1.1.2 is the latest).

The problem anyway may be related to the classpath you're using from Eclipse. You need to change it from Eclipse and use the `assembly` module I believe. In recent version the right module is called `mainRunner`.